# Can a c++ program have an switch statement inside an if/else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, error-handling, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I am trying to do a switch statement inside an if/else statement. It does not work. I am not sure if it is because the reserved word "break" that i use inside the switch statement takes me out of the function. Please help!!!

```
    /*  Date : March 3, 2015
    Date Due : March 23, 2015
    Program Name: Hospital Calculator
    Description: This program will ask the user to enter several information 
    related to his/her room floor measurements. After that, it will generate 
    a bill that will tell the customer the price for the carpet job.
    */

  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <string>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <cctype>

  //Constants
              // Room Rates
  const float SINGLE_ROOM    = 525.00,
              DOUBLE_ROOM    = 325.00,
              WARD           = 550.00,
              //Phone Access Rates
              SHARED_LINE    = 2.95,
              DEDICATED_LINE = 5.95,
              //Television Rates
              BASIC_CHANNELS = 2.95,
              CABLE_CHANNELS = 5.95;

  using namespace std;

    //Prototypes
  void getdata(string &, int &);
  float get_room ( int,  string &);
  float get_phone(int days, string &);  


  int main()
  {
     string name,
            room_type,
            phone_type,
            tv_type;

     int   days;

    float room_charges,
          phone_charges,
          tv_charges;

    //The ones below are subfuntions calls that devide each section    

  //Input section (call)
    getdata(name,days);
  //room_charges = 
  //room_charges = get_room(days,room_type);
  phone_charges = get_phone(days, phone_type);
  cout << phone_charges << endl;
  cout << phone_type << endl;

  /*tv_charges = get_tv(days, tv_type);
  print(name, days, room_charges, phone_charges, tv_charges);
  */

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
  }

  // Input Section
  //This function takes the information needed from the user
  void getdata(string & name, int & days)
  {
    string symbol;

    symbol.assign (50, '*');
    cout << symbol<< endl;
    cout << right << setw(22) << "\tCustomer's Name\t\t\t: ";
    getline (cin,name);
    cout << right << setw(22) << "\tNumber of days in the hospital\t\t: ";
    cin >> days;
    cout << symbol << endl; 
    cin.ignore();
  }

  float get_room ( int days, string & room_type)  
  {
      string choice;
      char   ch;
      float  room_charges;
      cout << "\n\n\t\t\tRoom Used\n";
      cout <<     "\t\t\t________\n\n";
      cout << fixed << setprecision (2);
      cout << "\t1- Single room-One bed \t"<< SINGLE_ROOM <<"\n\n";
      cout << "\t2- Double room-Two beds\t"<< DOUBLE_ROOM <<"\n\n";
      cout << "\t3- Ward                \t"<< WARD <<"\n\n";
      cout << "\t   Enter Choice 1, 2, or 3 : ";
      getline(cin, choice); 
      cin.ignore();
      ch = toupper(choice[0]);

      if (ch == '1' or ch == 'S')
         { 
            room_charges = SINGLE_ROOM * days;
            room_type    = "in a Single Room";
         }

      else if (ch == '2' or ch == 'D')
        { 
            room_charges = DOUBLE_ROOM * days;
            room_type    = "in a Double Room";
         }

      else if (ch == '3' or ch == 'W')
        {
            room_charges = WARD * days;
            room_type    = "in a Ward";
        }



      return room_charges;

  }

   float get_phone(int days, string & phone_type)

  {  
      string prompt,
             choice;
      char   pr, ch;
      float  phone_charges;
      cout << "Would you like Phone Access (Y/N): ";
      cin >> prompt;
      pr = toupper(prompt[0]);

      if (pr == 'Y') 
      {
          cout << "\n\n\t\t\tPhone Access\n";
          cout <<     "\t\t\t________\n\n";
          cout << "\t1- Shared   \t" << SHARED_LINE <<"\n\n";
          cout << "\t2- Dedicated\t"<< DEDICATED_LINE <<"\n\n";
          cout << "\t   Enter Choice 1 or 2: ";
          getline(cin, choice); 

          ch = toupper(choice[0]);

          if (ch == '1' or ch == 'S')
           { 
               phone_charges = (SHARED_LINE * days);
               phone_type    = "(Shared)";

           else if (ch == '2' or ch == 'D')     
             case '2':
             case 'D':        
              {
               phone_charges = (DEDICATED_LINE * days);
               phone_type    = "(Cable)";
               break;
              }  


           }


      }    

        else if (pr == 'N')
        {
          phone_charges = 0.00;
          phone_type = "None";
        }

         cin.ignore();
          return phone_charges;  

     }
```

Comment: Could you really not reduce this to a simple code example which shows the issue? Help us to help you.

Comment: I can't see a `switch` statement in your code, only a few `case` statements. They need to be use inside a `switch`.

Comment: Um, you don't have a `switch` inside an `if/else`. You have some `switch` `case` items inside an `if` which I assume is giving you a compile error for good reason. A `switch` statement usually starts with the keyword, `switch (...)...`. Specifically, a `switch (ch) {` after your `if (ch == '2' || ch == 'D')`. If you do the `switch` correctly, you can have it inside of an `if/else` block.

Answer (score 2):

A switch statement is not necessary here. But to keep with what you've already got, here are some fixes. You're missing a few brackets, and the `switch( ch )` itself.

```
      if (ch == '1' or ch == 'S')
      { 
           phone_charges = (SHARED_LINE * days);
           phone_type    = "(Shared)";
      } //<----- missing this
      else if (ch == '2' or ch == 'D')
      {
           switch( ch ) //<----- missing this
           {     //<------and this
               case '2':
                   //currently doing nothing, falls through to case 'D':
                   //break; <-----add this for the time being?
               case 'D':        

                   phone_charges = (DEDICATED_LINE * days);
                   phone_type    = "(Cable)";
                   break;


            }/// <-----and this
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not used the keyword 'switch'. The code should look like

```
else if(ch == '2' or ch == 'D'){
    switch(ch){
    case '2':
        break;
    case 'D':
         phone_charges = (DEDICATED_LINE * days);
         phone_type    = "(Cable)";
         break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you intended to leave the case for '2' blank but not having a break in each case results in fall through.

Comment: That would make it compile, but I doubt the code "should" look like that!

Comment: When I said "should", I was pointing specifically at the 'switch-case' construct.